# Change Xcode 5 file template value for ___FULLUSERNAME___

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode5

Is it possible to change the value Xcode 5 substitutes for `___FULLUSERNAME___` when expanding file templates? Looks like this was possible in the past [via defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6983301/1999152) but it now pulls from the system's full username.

My problem is that I have two user accounts, one work and one personal. I like this separation, however, OSX prevents setting the same full username value on both accounts. I was surprised by this restriction since I assumed it was just a UI thing since the underlying account names are obviously different. Alternatively, I would accept an answer that works around this limitation.

#### EDIT

I don't want to copy all the standard templates into `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File\ Templates/` and do a find a replace with my name since that creates duplicates of every template.

Comment: I always find the generated headers to be useless anyway and replace them with my own (manually edited).  Perhaps that is a solution?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the root templates get overwritten on SDK updates so that doesn't work that well.

Comment: @Kevin Can you explain or provide a source. If I dump $USER at the console I get 'work' as my username. However the OSX full user name is 'Neil Work' that I've entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieve this by renaming my user name of OS X, check [this document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548) by Apple.