# Change "Created by" _username_

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

How can I change the "Created by" when making a new file in Xcode 6.x?
Im using Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite

The old way doesn't work:

1. Updating the "current" Address Book name.
2. defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions `{"FULLUSERNAME" = "Name Here";}`

[image]

Comment: The template file I have uses `«FULLUSERNAME»`, not `_username_`. Try fixing your template file.

Comment: @rmaddy i've just replaced my real name with _username_

Comment: Huh? Replaced it where? I'm using Xcode 6 and when I create new files, templates that contain `«FULLUSERNAME»` get replaced with my actual name.

Comment: Where and how can I modify the "template" file?

Comment: Isn't that the template file in your question?

Comment: Its just the header ?

Comment: But is it the header of your template file or is the result of creating a new file from a template? Where did `_username_` come from?

Comment: This is the result of creating a new a new file from a template. 
When creating a new file the header says my full name but I just replaced the fullname with "_username_" for the sake of the screenshot

Comment: Now I'm really confused. So the resulting file actually did show your actual name. So what's the problem then?

Comment: I just want to be able to change it to something else.. like anything :)

Comment: Correct answer can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/27074406/2341744

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode - Change Company Name and Username](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245689/xcode-change-company-name-and-username)

Answer (score 59):

you can try:

System Preferences --> Users & Groups --> choose current User --> unlock -->right tap current User --> Advanced option --> change you full name & above account name to your want, save ,that is ok!

I get it from [How does Xcode know who the the project was "created by"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950074/how-does-xcode-know-who-the-the-project-was-created-by)   @Juzzz 's answer.

hope that will help.

Comment: yep! it's worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

In Xcode9 Apple added `FILEHEADER` text macro to allow you to do just that.

Comment: In case you're wondering how to actually implement that, here's a great article by [Ole Begemann](https://oleb.net/blog/2017/07/xcode-9-text-macros/)